# untar file without subdirectories containing it

Tags: directory, tar

I have a tar archive **foo.tar.gz**, inside of which a directory containing another directory contains a file: **folder_1/folder_2/file.txt**.

I want to untar **file.txt**  without extracting **folder_1/folder_2/**.

Using

```
tar -xvf foo.tar.gz folder_1/folder_2/file.txt
```

I get **file.txt** inside the subdirectories that contained it inside the tar archive (**folder_1/folder_2/file.txt**).

Is there a way of **getting only *file.txt* and nothing else** in a single command, avoiding extracting everything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can extract the file to standard output and redirect that:

```
tar -xvf foo.tar.gz -O folder_1/folder_2/file.txt > file.txt
```

(Note that the option is a capital “O”, not the digit “0”.)

Comment: I am getting this printed out, and my `file.txt` gets extracted without any content:

`tar: Options '-[0-7][lmh]' not supported by *this* tar
Try 'tar --help' or 'tar --usage' for more information.`

Comment: @tli Are you using `-O` (capital letter O), or `-0` (number 0)? The capital letter O option is a GNU tar extension to extract to `stdout`.

Comment: @AndrewHenle my bad, thanks for pointing that out, now it works!

Comment: The option is also supported on other platforms, *e.g.* FreeBSD.